# Ubuntu 'Failed to import the site module' error message With Python

Tags: python

The following error message below occurs when I try to run a python file with the command `python3 training.py`

I found a potential solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446220/linux-weird-python-output) but when I went to make the suggested change it appeared that my machine had what was considered the correct setup.

To clarify, I have did significant research and none of the following fixes work

- [GitHub 286](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/286)
- [1192890](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.3/+bug/1192890)
- [1480388](https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+bug/1480388)

Any suggestions to what it could be and how to fix it? I currently can't submit my course work because of this bug :(

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04